# how do i run python code in visual studio to create GCP bigquery dataset

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

can i use VS code to run python scripts to manipulate GCP big query like creating datasets

I have installed cloud code but the imports i have still dont resolve

example
from google.cloud import bigquery

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe cloud code gives you the relevant features you're asking about.  Have you setup environment(s) and installed the bigquery package?

Generally, VSCode talks about python here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_installing-packages

Specifically, the instructions for the bigquery package can be found here:

https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html#installation

The TL;DR is I'd expect you need to run something akin to `pip install google-cloud-bigquery` at some point during your project setup to pull in the bigquery package.

Comment: i have run the pip command and i have cloud code installed, i have not set up the jupyter notebooks in VS code but that doesnt recognise the module either